# Fill Colour according to Data in Excel Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am using an Excel worksheet to allocate work and their are 3-4 users in the Team. What I want to do is that based on some value I wish to allocate a task to a user (this step has been achieved with some VBA and Macros), the next step is to colour code each user. So, based on the name that appears in front of the task, the cell colour needs to change to reflect the user.

Basically, each user should automatically get a colour when his name comes up against any task. This colour will be consistent for that user and does not depend on the task.

Comment: You don't need a macro for this, you can use conditional formatting.

Comment: I have multiple Users to whom I want to allocate multiple colours. Wouldn't Conditional Formatting be too cumbersome for this work? As I will need to provide a condition for each user in this case?

Comment: You can use the worksheet_change event to update the cell color based on the name.

Comment: You could combine the two by using a UDF in a Conditional format

Comment: that would be something I am looking for? is there any such UDF existing, which I can reuse and modify according to the requirements?

Comment: @TimWilliams: is there any example of this event, which I can look at and try to re-use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If names are in the first column:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim clr As Long, c As Range, v

    For Each c In Target.Cells
        If c.Column = 1 Then
            v = c.Value
            clr = -1
            If Len(v) > 0 Then
                Select Case v
                Case "Fred": clr = vbRed
                Case "Jeff": clr = vbBlue
                Case "Jane": clr = vbYellow
                End Select
            End If
            If clr > 0 Then
                c.Interior.Color = clr
            Else
                c.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```